# using python, look at the contents of a compressed file without reading the entire file

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Using python, I want to look at the contents of a .zip (deflate) **without reading the entire file.** I have a very slow network drive containing lots of compressed files.  I would like to be able to open a file and look at the contents without downloading the entire file first.

For contrast, when opening a .zip using windows 10 file explorer, it downloads the entire file. On the other hand,  7zip "Open Archive" lets you see the contents without downloading the entire file.

How can I do this with python.  I've tried using the following code but like the windows10 file explorer, it downloads the entire file before printing the file names.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("filename.zip") as zip_obj:
    for sub_file in zip_obj.namelist():
        print(sub_file.filename)
```

Comment: I think you need to use the method `ZipFile.namelist()`.

Comment: @cesarv that was a typo. I fixed it